# Tools for project management Data Science

Tags: tools, project-planning, management

I'm in charge of a small data science team (3 data scientists, me included). We do our projects with at least one business person (PM) per project ( we have 5 of these).

We managed everything with meetings and emails, but as the number of projects and people keeps increasing, I find it necessary to have a proper management tool.

I would like to have something were we could, per project, add business needs (requirements). These requirements could translate into coding actions. One could estimate the time needed for each action.

It should be possible to then assign these tasks to DSs, and organise the priority to be given to each task. This way the whole team could see what need to be done in each project, what each DS is going to do after, and when each task is going to be completed.

I'm looking for a free or very cheap solution. I looked at Jira, but I'm not sure if it's a good solution.

Comment: What about Excel? You can easily set up a Gantt chart etc.

Answer (score 4):

Data science project planning is carried out through any of the scrum application such as Jira, Asana or even using Github projects. Gitlab also offers efficient tools for the same. Once you are done with planning, you can use open-source projects such as Git-lfs and DVC to version control your datasets. The notebooks that you prepare could also be version controlled in Github or Gitlab. You can easily find courses and tutorials to dynamically set up your boards and workflows in Github as well as Gitlab.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira), [Trello](https://trello.com/), [Azure Devops](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/), and [Github](https://www.github.com) Issues+Projects+Discussions for Data Science project and program management.  The limiting factor is not the software, but your team's dedication to work in the system.  Jira is my favorite out of all of them.  Trello and Github are both great free options.